# Contacts and settings does not open on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-2.3

I installed **android sdk 3.1 and 2.3.3** And i created emulator using both of them.

But when i run **3.1(api level 12)** emulator it doesn't work some features(applications) like **contact,settings but in 2.3.3(api level 1)** it works well.

I don't know why.So i re-installed them few times and the result was same.After i asked this about others and they had the same experience.can anyone explain why this happened?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dear the aplication u have been running in api 12 is not compatible with it... it must run on lower api. Application execution differs in api levels.
u must try to run ur application in api 1 if u have developed application in android 2.3.3.

Comment: Actually i'm not referring here about a my application.